Introduction to the theory of $D$-modules and the role of the characteristic cycle
I am seeking recommendations for a concise introduction to the theory of $D$-modules suitable for an algebraic geometer. Specifically, I am interested in understanding:

The role of the characteristic cycle in the theory.
The analogies and relations between $D$-modules, $l$-adic cohomology, and ramification theory.

All in all, I would like to properly understand the first sentences of the introduction of this excellent paper of Tomoyuki Abe.  Alternatively, a response explaining these two questions, rather than a reference, would also be greatly appreciated.

I don't know a good reference giving an introduction to the characteristic cycle in the theory of $D$-modules (this is entirely ignorance on my part and not a reflection of a dearth of references in the literature). However, once you find such a reference, the second part, understanding the analogy, should be relatively straightforward:

Essentially every result on the characteristic cycle of $\ell$-adic sheaves in the paper of Saito (or followup papers) will have a direct analogue in the theory of holonomic $D$-modules by more-or-less one-for-one translating each term to the other setting. The converse is not quite true - in particular the key statement that characteristic cycles have Lagrangian support is false in the $\ell$-adic setting in characteristic $p$, as Saito observes.

I think https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/north-holland-mathematical-library/vol/21/suppl/C addresses the first of these.

Also for the first part, there is a book by Hotta, Tankeuchi, Tanasaki on D-modules which is quite good.
